# Add module to sub controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a ASP.NET masterpage in which I have the div containing the `ng-app` attribute. Also
the masterpages `main.js` defines `mainController`.

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div ng-controller="subController">
  </div>
</div>
```

in which the inner div is not part of the master page.

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module("foo", ["ng"]);

app.controller("mainController", function ()
{

});
```

In a page using the master page, I define `subController`.
in which I want to use the module `angularSpectrumColorpicker`.

However, I do not want to add that module to the app like `var app = angular.module("foo", ["ng", "angularSpectrumColorpicker"]);` since that would affect the main controller.

Is it possible to add the module to the sub controller instead of to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not affect your main controller. It affects your module called `foo` since you inject the module called `angularSpectrumColorpicker` there.

There is no way to solve this in the way you want (and there is also no need to do it like you want to do it). Modules are injected into other modules globally. You can `angular.module('ng').requires.push('angularSpectrumColorpicker');` but this only load the module dynamically into your `foo` module with the same affect.

---

You could also load this module with lazy loading like in this **[example plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TFapGiZGs30L5vOwK0Iz?p=preview)**. Also this does inject the module globally into `foo` once it has been loaded:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var App = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        // You can also load via resolve
        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                "lazyLoadView": {
                    template: 'Hello world'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                test: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'angularSpectrumColorpicker',
                        files: ['angular-spectrum-colorpicker.min.js'] 
                    });
                }]
            }
        });

        // Without server side support html5 must be disabled.
        return $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }])
    .config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            asyncLoader: $script
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: That means I need to add `<script src="ExtLibs/spectrum/angular-spectrum-colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to my master page instead of the page in which I use a color picker?

Comment: I solved the problem by having a sub module as well.